# Verify if a method is invoked dynamically using Moq and Nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I want to dynamically verify if a particular method of a class is being called or not not based on the inputs passed.

```cs
public interface ISample
{
  int GetNumber(string input);
  string GetString(string input);
}

public class A : ISample
{
 public int GetNumber(string input)
 {
   // some implementation
 }

 public int GetString(string input)
 {
   // some implementation
 }
}

public class B : ISample
{
 public int GetNumber(string input)
 {
   // some implementation different from A
 }

 public int GetString(string input)
 {
   // some implementation different from A
 }
}

public class CFactory
{
 public ISample GetObject(string decidingInput)
 {
  // return either A or B based on input
 }
}
```

There is a different class that make use of factory to get corresponding object and then use that object to invoke `GetNumber` or `GetString` method on the object.

```cs
public class InvokeMethodClass
{
public object invokeMethod(string decidingInput, string ifClause)
{
var iSample = new CFactory(decidingInput);
if(string.equals(ifClause, "int"))
{
return isample.GetNumber("something");
}
else
{
return isample.GetString("something");
}
}
}
```

Assuming that there are lot of methods defined in interface similar to `GetNumber`,`GetString` and each of those methods being implemented in both class `A` and `B`. I would like to unit test these methods using data source instead of writing individual tests to check if a method is invoked or not.

```cs
Mock<ISample> _iSample = new Mock<ISample>();
[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(_methodNames))]
public void SampleTest(string methodName)
{
var invokeMethodClass = new InvokeMethodClass();
var result = invokeMethodClass.invokeMethod("createA", "int");

// assert
Assert.NotNull(result);
// this works.
_iSample.verify(x => x.GetNumber(It.Is<string>()), Times.AtLeast(1));
// this is not working.
_iSample.verify(x => x.GetType().GetMethod("GetNumber").Invoke(new A()), Times.AtLeast(1));
}
```

I want to pass the method name to the test method using data source defined in the setup. By trying to call method name dynamically using reflections is not working.

Is there a better solution for this problem or what wrong with using reflections to call the method??

Comment: Moq works with expression. Using reflection directly wont work as you have already discovered. You could look into building the expression tree dynamically based on the member name but that is more work than it is worth. Another option would be to pass in the expression instead of just the name.  Also consider abstracting the factory and injecting it as a dependency into the subject under test. The current mock is not being used in the test.

Comment: `I would like to unit test these methods using data source instead of writing individual tests to check if a method is invoked or not.` Why? How would you know which one is being called and which is not called? Unit tests should be straight forward and easy to write.

Comment: @CodingYoshi `WHY?` its because i don't want to write same code again and again to check if each method is being invoked or not. `How will i know which one is called?`.  If you look at `CFactory` class it has `GetObject ` which takes in some input and gives corresponding object. Yes, i agree that unit tests should be easy to write, but the problem i don't want to write duplicate code.